# Как заставить бота работать 24/7 не на компьютере?

Tags: java, сервер, telegram-bot, бот, discord-api

Я разработал бота (написан на Java для Discord). На данный момент бота запускаю через компилятор на компьютере, но хотел бы, чтобы мой бот работал непрерывно 24/7. Как я понимаю, мне нужен Java-север или что-то другое?

Уверен, данный вопрос актуален еще тем, кто пишет бота для Telegram и vk.com

Comment: речь о хостинге?

Comment: @Anatol да. На я уже подумал над Heroku. Но у меня возникли сложности при добавлении проекта на него. Проект вроде загрузился, но он мне выдает какую-ту ошибку... Пока ее не гуглил

Comment: вопрос сформулирован некорректно, нет явно обозначенной проблемы. такие вопросы закрываются. если есть актуальная проблема, то опишите её подобающим образом

Comment: @Antonio112009 на бесплатном тарифе heroku останавливает приложения, если к ним нет обращения с внешней стороны.

Comment: @dmtr да этот вопрос уже не актуален. Решил просто привести его в порядок, а получилось, что он заново вывел его в главные на СО

Comment: @Antonio112009 я даже не заметил)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте хостинг. [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/)(для крутых, т.к. не дешево) и т.п. - [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/)(его рекомендуют), [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), [Hostinger](https://www.hostinger.mx/) тоже неплох.

Вот хорошая [статья](https://habr.com/post/274587/)(Веб-платформа на Java за 30 минут), как быстро развернуть web-приложение Java на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Для развертывания Java-бота (да и вообще любого другого бота, написанного на других языках) не стоит искать специальный Java-сервер. В данном случае нам понадобится выделенный сервер (dedicated server) или VPS (Virtual Private Server). Web-Hosting - это для хостинга сайтов, а значит нам данный вариант не подходит.

Из моего личного опыта, лучший VPS-провайдер - это Digital Ocean, однако он дорогой и если вы из России, то готовьтесь к тому, что многие запросы на Российские сервера будут недоступны (привет Рос****надзору).

Я бы лучше брал dedicated server. Один из лучших провайдеров выделенных серверов - OVH. Сервера дорогие и поэтому я порекомендовал бы их дочернюю компанию - https://www.kimsufi.com/. Если у вас бот не многозадачен, то за 5-6 евро сервера вам будет сверхдостаточно.

Что же делать после покупки сервера?
Лично я люблю Ubuntu (хотя с ней немало хлопот можно словить) и через командную строку (на сервере) устанавливаете OpenJDK, потом перекидываете по FTP executable jar file (запускаемый Jar-файл). Далее запускаем приложение в фоновом режиме. Если вы просто запустите приложение на сервере и закроете консоль, то программа ваша автоматически завершится.

Как запустить в фоновом режиме приложение?
Создаем файл `/etc/systemd/system/myapplication.service`

```
[Unit]
Description= # Place a descriptive application name here
After=syslog.target
After=network.target[Service]
User= # Define a user account that will own our app. Example: root
Type=simple

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar # Provide /path/to/file/myapplication.jar
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier= # A short identifier for system journal, f. e. 'myapplication'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`sudo systemctl start/stop/restart myapplication` 
`start` - запускает бота
`stop` - останавливает бота
`restart` - перезапускает бота (можно использовать команду при обновлении jar-файла с ботом)

На этом все